# Only update the date I change others state should not update or change ReactJS/React-Hooks

Tags: javascript, datepicker, react-hooks, react-datepicker

Through new concept of react hooks I wanna post some data I am using useState future so when I change a date other dates also updated that what ı choose. I want it to be update only related date. if ı change planRegisterStartDate so others should not effect how can ı do it ı usereact-datepicker package

```
const [planGroupData, setPlanGroupData] = useState({
    planGroupName: '',
    PlanGroupYear: '',
    planRegisterStartDate: new Date(),
    planRegisterFinishDate: new Date(),
    projeRegisterStartDate: new Date(),
    projeRegisterFinishDate: new Date()
  })

  const onPlanGroupDateChange = date => {
    setPlanGroupData({
      planRegisterStartDate: date,
      planRegisterFinishDate: date,
      projeRegisterStartDate: date,
      projeRegisterFinishDate: date
    })
  }
const {
    PlanGroupYear,
    planGroupName,
    planRegisterFinishDate,
    planRegisterStartDate,
    projeRegisterFinishDate,
    projeRegisterStartDate
  } = planGroupData

 return (
 <div className='form-row'>
          <DatePicker
            selected={planRegisterStartDate}
            onChange={onPlanGroupDateChange}
          />
 <DatePicker
            selected={planRegisterFinishDate}
            onChange={onPlanGroupDateChange}
          />
        </div>
)
```

Comment: if anyone has a good approach I can follow it

Answer (score 1):

You can separate your states and define set functions individually, and then you can call those functions  in their respective components. It will be more manageable in my opinion.

```js
const [planGroupName, setPlanGroupName] = useState(null)
const [planGroupYear, setPlanGroupYear] = useState(null)
const [planRegisterStartDate, setPlanRegisterStartDate] = useState(new Date())
const [planRegisterFinishDate, setPlanRegisterFinishDate] = useState(new Date())
const [projeRegisterStartDate, setProjeRegisterStartDate] = useState(new Date())
const [projeRegisterFinishDate, setProjeRegisterFinishDate] = useState(new Date())


<DatePicker selected={planRegisterStartDate}
            onChange={date => setPlanRegisterStartDate(date)} />
<DatePicker selected={planRegisterFinishDate} 
             onChange={date => setPlanRegisterFinishDate(date)} />
```